How to send audio to fake mic and control it from test code
I want my Playwright test to play audio, so my Chromium app can record it. Following this answer, I can launch Chromium with -use-file-for-fake-audio-capture param. But, this mean that the audio starts as soon as the app starts, and not when I want it to.
How do I start the playback during somewhere in my test? Pseudo-code:
    test("mytest", async () => {
        // Open my app
        // Navigate to a voice-recognition page
        await page.SomehowPlayAudioFile("myfile.wav");
        // verify that the words in myfile.wav were entered
    });


Can I ask what do you plan to test?

My app uses voice recognition, so I want to test "open app, navigate to screen X, dictate word from mic, verify that the word is entered in the app"
